# Similarities between "The Equalizer" and "Hitman: Absolution"

Tags: plot-explanation, the-equalizer

I was wondering that the movie *The Equalizer* is so much like the game *Hitman: Absolution*, like the way the protagonist kills and the music. Especially the one track that plays right after Pushkin dies is so much similar to *Absolution's* signature music which is played throughout the cutscenes in important key sequences.

Is there any chance that this movie was inspired by *Hitman:Absolution*?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any interviews which discuss inspirations for the style of the film or its music. However, The Equalizer itself isn't inspired by Hitman: Absolution, but by the original [Television series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088513/), which ran from 1985-1989. Edward Woodward played Robert McCall, an ex-CIA operative who takes an ad in the paper offering help to those who need it. The TV McCall appears to be more of an old-school spy than a black-ops guy, though he still shoots quite a few people.

Comment: well what you explained was the inspiration on story and characters, but my question was different, the signature music when he kills someone in the movie is much similar to the signature music played at the end of hitman absolution's missions, also the methods he uses to kill his opponents are so similar to hitman absolution , killing brutally by anything found in the surroundings . but anyway since you answered and pointed out a left out yet significant point i will vote it up

Comment: My first sentence was meant to convey that I found nothing explicit which stated any source for the style inspiration, including music. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: I mean, I also see the similarities, but can't back up the observation with any properly sourced facts.

Comment: yeah , i get what you say